# Why pop-up don't show and don't delete the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with part of my code. I am learning Ruby on Rails. I am using (https://youtu.be/2_Lbj3slZUY?t=1939).
I have problem with line 9 of the code. Nothing happening after clicking on delete button. No pop-up window, nothing. I dont know ho wo fix it. :)

```rb
= link_to "Back", root_path  
= link_to "Edit", edit_workout_path(@workout)
= link_to "Delete", workout_path(@workout), method: :delete, data: {confirm:  "Text"}
```

Comment: can you inspect on the view in browser and check that html line and give the line here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby On Rails, what makes the 'data-confirm' display a popup is the `jquery_ujs` gem.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery#documentation

> The presence of this attribute indicates that activating a link or
>   submitting a form should be intercepted so the user can be presented a
>   JavaScript confirm() dialog containing the text that is the value of
>   the attribute. If the user chooses to cancel, the action doesn't take
>   place.

Make sure it is in your `Gemfile` and that it is included in your `application.js`, as the docs say: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation-using-the-jquery-rails-gem